# SEGMENTATION fault while using a boringssl library

Tags: openssl, boringssl

When I run the following piece of code on  my terminal it gives segmentation fault .
I am using boringssl library.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
using namespace std;

// #include <openssl/digest.h>
int main(){
    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx);

    const EVP_MD* sha256 = EVP_sha256();
    EVP_DigestInit(ctx,sha256);

    char str[]="ANIKET GUPTA";
    EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx,str,strlen(str));

    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int* hash_size;
    EVP_DigestFinal(ctx,hash,hash_size);

    cout <<"SUCCESS";
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

I run this code using following command:  `g++ -I~/src/boringssl/include sign.cpp ~/src/boringssl/build/crypto/libcrypto.a -lpthread`
 What is the error which is giving segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

In the lines

```
unsigned int* hash_size;
EVP_DigestFinal(ctx, hash, hash_size);
```

you are using `hash_size` while it is uninitialized and the `EVP_DigestFinal()` will try to write the `hash_size` result into an unknown location, causing the segfault. Instead, you can do

```
unsigned int hash_size;
EVP_DigestFinal(ctx, hash, &hash_size);
```

Your compiler should have given you an indication of this problem, it is usually capable of detecting uninitialized variables like this.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
We have to malloc hash and hash_size

Comment: Well done :-). However, in this situation you would typically not malloc hash_size. Instead, declare it as an `unsigned int` and take its address -- see my answer for an example. There was nothing wrong with your `hash` variable, no need to `malloc` that either.